# ocv_add_module breaks execution of cMake file

Tags: matlab, opencv, cmake

I am trying to configure a MSVS Comunity 2017 project to get opencv 3.4.1 Matlab 2017 bindings using cMake 3.9.6.
In cMake I always obtain this two messages regarding the matlab module:

```
Warning: Matlab bindings will only be built in Release configurations
```

and

```
Matlab:                        YES
mex:                         C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/mex.bat
Compiler/generator:          Not working (bindings will not be generated)
```

I have edited the CMakeList.txt of the opencv_contrib matlab module, to debug the file. I have added two messages in the configure time components (line 102) as follows:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Configure time components
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
set(the_description "The Matlab/Octave bindings")

message(WARNING "Message 1")

ocv_add_module(matlab   BINDINGS
                       OPTIONAL  opencv_core
                                 opencv_imgproc opencv_ml
                                 opencv_imgcodecs opencv_videoio opencv_highgui
                                 opencv_objdetect opencv_flann opencv_features2d
                                 opencv_photo opencv_video opencv_videostab
                                 opencv_calib opencv_calib3d
                                 opencv_stitching opencv_superres
                                 opencv_xfeatures2d
)

message(WARNING "Message 2")
```

If everything be OK "Message 1" and "Message 2" should appear in CMake configuration process. When I configure the project with cMake only "Message 1" appears.

```
Found tiny-dnn in: C:/Datos/opencv-3.4.1/build/3rdparty/tinydnn/tiny-dnn-1.0.0a3
The protocol buffer compiler is not found (PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE='')
freetype2:   NO
harfbuzz:    NO
Warning: Matlab bindings will only be built in Release configurations


CMake Warning at modules/opencv_contrib-3.4.1/modules/matlab/CMakeLists.txt:116 (message):
  Message 1


Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
```

"Message 2", never ever appears. It seems like ocv_add_module command breaks the execution of the cMake file.

Can someone help me to understand what is happening?

Thanks in advance for your information.